# (Vue.js) V-model array. Having difficulty running function

Tags: arrays, function, vue.js, vuejs2, v-model

I'm working with a portfolio project, where users can upload a picture, provide a description below it, and then click the "add" button to add another image and description.

I'm trying to add a character counter to the description input, which is a `textarea` field. Usually I can add the name of the `v-model` into the function, and it works fine, but this `textarea` is in a `for`-loop, so I'm not sure how to get this function to work.

*Template:*

```html
<div class="newPortfolioList">
    <div class="newPortfolioItem" v-for="(item, index) in this.portfolioItems" v-bind:key="index">
....
       <div class="newPortfolioDescription">
          <textarea v-model="item.portfolioDescription" @keyup='remaincharCount()' maxlength="1000" placeholder="Item Description..."></textarea>
       </div>

       <!--  Displaying the remaining characters -->
       <span style="text-align:left; padding: 10px;">{{ remaincharactersText }}</span>
    </div>
...
```

*Script:*

```js
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            portfolioItems:[],
            maxcharacter: 1000,
            remaincharactersText: "1000 characters remaining"            
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createPortfolioItem () {
            this.portfolioItems.push({
                portfolioDescription: ''
            })
        },
        remaincharCount () {
            if (this.foo.length > this.maxcharacter) {
              this.remaincharactersText = "Exceeded "+this.maxcharacter+" characters limit.";
            } else {
              var remainCharacters = this.maxcharacter - this.foo.length;
              this.remaincharactersText = remainCharacters + " characters remaining";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just use the `maxlength` html attribute on textarea: `<textarea maxlength="1000">` ? you can also use a library like [Vee-validate](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#max) which allows you to check your validation rule and display error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware that the textarea already has its `maxlength` set to 1000, so the label `Exceeded N characters limit` isn't possible (unless you check for fewer than 1000). Currently, the label always would display `N reminaing characters`.

### Option 1: Display count calculation inline

Instead of storing the character count (unnecessarily taking up extra memory), you could display the calculation inline with string interpolation:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="item.portfolioDescription" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
    <span>{{ 1000 - item.portfolioDescription.length }} remaining characters</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RmRZrx?editors=1010)

### Option 2: Display count from item variable

If you prefer storing the character count (e.g., for some internal processing), you could add a new property to the item data:

```html
<script>
const MAXLEN = 1000

export default {
  methods: {
    createPortfolioItem() {
      this.portfolioItems.push({
        remainChars: MAXLEN, // <--
      })
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Then, update `item.remainChars` upon the `textarea`'s [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)-event, and display `item.remainChars` inline.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="item.portfolioDescription" maxlength="1000"
              @input="item.remainChars = 1000 - item.portfolioDescription.length">
    </textarea>
    <span>{{ item.remainChars }} remaining characters</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/EzyvjP?editors=1010)

### Option 3: Display computed text

You could [compute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) the character-count labels in a separate array that corresponds to `portfolioItems`:

```html
<script>
const MAXLEN = 1000

export default {
  computed: {
    remainingCharsText() {
      return this.portfolioItems.map(item => `${MAXLEN - item.portfolioDescription.length} remaining characters`)
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Then, update your template to reference this computed array by `index`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="item.portfolioDescription" maxlength="1000">
    </textarea>
    <span>{{ remainingCharsText[index] }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo 3](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JqKNWB?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This was perfect! I ended up using the first option. Thank you again!!

Comment: @asdf123 No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you could do this.

In this case I think your best option is to introduce a new component to represent a single portfolio item. Each of these components can manage their own message. From their perspective there is no loop to consider.

So you'd have something like this for your list template:

```
<div class="newPortfolioList">
    <my-new-portfolio-item
        v-for="(item, index) in portfolioItems"
        :key="index"
        :portfolio-item="item"
    />
</div>
```

Two side notes. I've dropped the `v-bind` prefix on your key, a `:` will suffice. I've also removed the `this.` before `portfolioItems` as that's also unnecessary. The Vue linting rules can be used to help keep this stuff in check.

There are alternatives to introducing a new component. You could generate the value of `remaincharactersText` within the template rather than keeping it in state. It could still be a method call but it wouldn't be precalculated. Something like this:

```
<span style="text-align:left; padding: 10px;">{{ remaincharCount(item) }}</span>
```

A further (even more painful) alternative would be to make `remaincharactersText` an array of values and then grab the relevant one by index:

```
<span style="text-align:left; padding: 10px;">{{ remaincharactersText[index] }}</span>
```

But, to reiterate, introducing a separate component for the items within the `v-for` is probably the best way to go here.